# How to integrate this trigonometry function?

Tags: calculus, integration

The question is $ \displaystyle \int{ \frac{1-r^{2}}{1-2r\cos(\theta)+r^{2}}} d\theta$.

I know it will be used weierstrass substitution to solve but i did not have any idea of it.

Comment: Quotient rule? I'm familiar with a quotient rule for differentiation, but not with a quotient rule for integration. Can you tell us what you mean here by "quotient rule"?

Comment: @GerryMyerson: i am sorry, my mistake.. it is actually involving weierstrass substitution..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apply the substitution $$\tan \frac{\theta}{2}=t.$$ Then use $\cos\theta=\frac{1-t^2}{1+t^2}$.

Comment: how to apply $\tan{\frac{\theta}{2}}=t$ ?

Comment: Then $sec^2(\theta/2).1/2 d\theta=dt\Rightarrow d\theta=\frac{2dt}{1+t^2}$. Now transform everything into $t$.

Comment: @Norlyda, I have seen a similar question here (in this site) just within one hour...but unable to find it. It would be helpful if someone post link here.

Comment: the problems occurs when I try to factorize the denominator in order to use integration by partial fraction. do you have any idea?

Comment: @Norlyda, No partial fraction will be necessary. Your integration will boil into $2(1-r^2)\int\frac{dt}{(1+r)^2t^2+(1-r)^2}$. The denominator is of the form $ax^2+b=a(x^2+b/a)$.  So the formula $\int\frac{dx}{x^2+a^2}=\frac{1}{a}\tan^{-1}(\frac{x}{a})$ will be used.

Comment: tqsm.. really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

There's a Wikipedia article about this technique: [Weierstrass substitution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass_substitution).

Notice that what you've got here is $\displaystyle\int\frac{d\theta}{a+b\cos\theta}$.  The factor $1-r^2$ pulls out, and $a=1+r^2$ and $b=-2r$.

Comment: the problems occurs when I try to factorize the denominator in order to use integration by partial fraction. do you have any idea?